# Unity C# Voxel finite water optimization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voxel, compute-shader

I got a (basic) voxel engine running and a water system that looks (and I assume basically works) like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_TdeGIOOts (not my game).  
The water values are stored in a 3d Array of floats, and every 0.05s it calculates water flow by checking the voxel below and adjacent (y-1, x-1, x+1, z-1, z+1) and adds the value.  
This system works fine (70+ fps) for small amounts of water, but when I start calculating water on 8+ chunks, it gets too much. 
(I disabled all rendering or mesh creation to check if that is the bottleneck, it isnt. Its purely the flow calculations).  
I am not a very experienced programmer so I wouldnt know where to start optimizing, apart from making the calculations happen in a coroutine as I already did.  
In this post: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55414/how-to-define-areas-filled-with-water (near the bottom) Boreal suggests running it in a **compute shader**. Is this the way to go for me? And how would I go about such a thing? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really calculating a voxel based simulation, you will be expanding the number of calculations geometrically as your size increases, so you will quickly run out of processing power on larger volumes.

A compute shader is great for doing massively parallel calculations quickly, although it's a very different programming paradigm that takes some getting used to.  A compute shader will look at the contents of a buffer (ie, a 'texture' for us civilians)  and do things to it very quickly -- in your case the buffer will probably be a buffer/texture whose pixel values represent water cells.  If you want to do something really simple like increment them up or down the compute shader uses the parallel processing power of the GPU to do it really fast.

The hard part is that GPUs are [optimized for parallel processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units#Programmability). This means that you can't write code like  "texelA.value += texelB.value" - without extra work on your part, each fragment of the buffer is processed with zero knowledge of what happens in the other fragments.  To reference other texels you need to read the texture again somehow - some techniques read one texture multiple times with offsets ([this GL example](http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/11/gaussian-blur-filter-shader/) does this to implement blurs, others do it by repeatedly processing a texture, putting the result into a temporary texture and then reprocessing that.

At the 10,000 foot level: yes, a compute shader is a good tool for this kind of problem since it involves tons of self-similar calculation. But, it won't be easy to do off the bat. If you have not done conventional shader programming before, You may want to look at that first to get used to the way GPUs work.  Even really basic tools (if-then-else or loops) have very different performance implications and uses in GPU programming and it takes some time to get your head around the differences.  As of this writing (1/10/13) it looks like [Nvidia and Udacity are offering an intro to compute shader course](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) which might be a good way to get up to speed.

FWIW you also need pretty modern hardware for compute shaders, which may limit your audience.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer! I'll look into it though I get the feeling I'm not at that level yet. Also realized that if I ever want to 'unload' chunks, the finite water calculations become a real pain to continue... Wondering how others do that (like this god among men: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9mGczbvoc0). Well thanks again!